# What is the point of using shared module in app.module?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the use of using Shared Module and reffering that shared module in app.module.ts.

Every time the page is loaded, app.module.ts in turn calls shared module.

Instead, we could omit shared module and refer all components directly in the app.module.ts file instead of shared module.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to add shared module into app module, you can just import it to which ever module requires it.

Comment: Readability is why we're using modules. You could also create a single app component that is 70.000 lines long, nothing prevents you from doing that.

Comment: There's also the reusability side, which allows you to use this shared module in other projects just by copy-pasting the folder.

Comment: The official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) explain this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components must be declared only once but available to other component in multiple modules. [SharedModule](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) come to the rescue - it is the place where components is declared once but by import SharedModule that components(exported) is available as dependencies for others.

As a better solution we can make RootModule with all reusable pipe, directives, components across whole app. All other component should be created as a module. For example check [ngBootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/tree/development/src). It allow us to have better code splitting across chunks as all modules depend on what they really use.